# tableView.dequeueReusableCellwithIdentifier: "", forindexPath) trigger All Excepts breakpoints

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, breakpoints, xcode11

When I opened the `All Excepts` breakpoints, my program stops at `tableView.dequeueReusableCellwithIdentifier`. -Xcode 11- Click continue program execution, App didn't crash. Why?

[image]

Comment: ok, first of all: with what error does you app crash? We need error message for clarification. and can you add code snippets for ```func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell ```. As I see, you try to force unwrapp the cell to ```JTCustomerMineCell```, the problem could be there, but I can only guess without code.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the keyword private. This causes Cocoa (which is Objective-C) to be unable to see that you have implemented the JTCustomerMainCell class It can't see it so it doesn't call it. Delete that keyword and you're good to go.
Check & find like this

```
private class JTCustomerMainCell: UITableViewCell {
(...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the cell first.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    tableView.register(JTCustomerMainCell, forCellReuseIdentifier: "JTCustomerMainCell")
}
```